# restrict direct file download from crystal report hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, form-authentication

I have crystal report in which i show file url path ,its a hyperlink when user click on that link.. file is able to view/download.

i mean in crystal report url is like

```
http://localhost:1645/websitename/Attachments/abc.pdf
```

file type could be of doc,docx,pdf,jpeg,png etc..
I mean from a form user upload files to this attachmnet folder then from report they can view/download these files.

Now problem is these files are directly accessible.I can directly type url and can download without login.

Now how do i restrict this kind of scenario. I have implemented form authentication but that works on forms but this is direct file type.

Now how do i restrict this.

Answer (score 0):

Forms authentication is not restricted to forms.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions available

1. Using a ashx handler. You may need to pass the filename as query string / some other format.
2. By mapping *.PDF or any other static file to aspnet_isapi.dll.